# save Embed docs as an object using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this

```
 const user = new Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String , required: true},
    phone:{type: Number, unique true}
    embeddedDocsAsJson: {} // not as an array 
 },
   { minimize: false }
)
```

I want to use embeddedDocsAsJson because of two reasons

1. In case of array a duplicate data can be pushed to array , if I use json it will not occur as I'll use `unique id` as `json` key
2. Retrieval will be faster as I don't have to iterate  on the array . I can fetch it from the `json key`

**Problem**: 
Firstly I'm inserting `firstName and lastName phone`.

And `embeddedDocsAsJson` is added while updating the docs below is my code for updating

```
   let user = await User.findOne({phone: somenumber})
   user.embeddedDocsAsJson.someId = someObject // getting error in this line because `user.embeddedDocsAsJson` is `undefined`
   user.save()
```

I'm adding value to `embeddedDocsAsJson` while updating

Comment: have you tried setting user.embeddedDocsAsJson = {} first ?

Comment: It worked ... But I have already defined in its schema that doesn't work bdw thnQ

Comment: by setting  embeddedDocsAsJson: {} you are not setting its default value as {}

Comment: defining it in the schema does not set it by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmbeddedDocs are by-default array if you want to save object in your collection below code will  work.

```
    let user = await User.findOne({phone: somenumber})
    user.embeddedDocsAsJson = {} 
    user.embeddedDocsAsJson.someId = someObject // getting error in this line because `user.embeddedDocsAsJson` is `undefined`
    user.save()
```